# Llenar una matriz usando for, a través de una condición en C#

Tags: c#, bucle-for, condiciones

Estoy haciendo un programa para llenar una matriz según se cumplan diferentes condiciones, una de ellas es que para colocar un numero dentro de la matriz, este debe ser mayor de mil o de lo contrario le pida un numero nuevo al usuario, el problema es que no logro hacer que la condición funcione junto con el for. ¿Alguien sabrá como hacerlo?

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int filas=0;
            int columnas=0;

            Console.WriteLine("¿De cuantas filas?");
            filas= int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("¿De cuantas columnas?");
            columnas = int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());

            while (filas > 10 | columnas > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("no se puede, tiene que ser menor a 10");

                Console.WriteLine("¿De cuantas filas?");
                filas = int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("¿De cuantas columnas?");
                columnas = int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
            }

            int[,] tamaño = new int[filas, columnas];

            Console.WriteLine("dame un numero");

            for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++)
                {
                    if (tamaño [i,j]<1000)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("tiene que ser mayor a 1000");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("dame un valor de [" + i + "," + j + "]:");
                        tamaño[i, j] = int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                                       
                }
            }


            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Dónde pone valores en tamaño[,]?  Y es ñ un caracter valida para un nombre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te falta un bucle while dentro del segundo for para iterar permanentemente hasta que el usuario especifique el numero correcto, por otra parte, también tienes un <1000 cuando debería ser "<=1000".

Prueba con esta función:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            int filas=0;
            int columnas=0;

            Console.WriteLine("¿De cuantas filas?");
            filas= int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("¿De cuantas columnas?");
            columnas = int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());

            while (filas > 10 | columnas > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("no se puede, tiene que ser menor a 10");

                Console.WriteLine("¿De cuantas filas?");
                filas = int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("¿De cuantas columnas?");
                columnas = int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
            }

            int[,] tamaño = new int[filas, columnas];


            for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++)
                {
                    tamaño[i, j] = 0;
                    while (tamaño[i, j] <= 1000)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("dame un valor de [" + i + "," + j + "]:");
                        tamaño[i, j] = int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
                        
                        if(tamaño[i, j] <= 1000)
                            Console.WriteLine("tiene que ser mayor a 1000");
                    }                 
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
    }
```